# Speeding up records filtering as and when user types

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-3.5

My application is in C# [.NET 3.5] and MySQL 5.1 back-end.

I have a Windows Form with a TextBox and a DataGridView. When the user types in few characters in the TextBox, an SQL Query with a Like clause is run to filter the records shown in the DataGridView below.

The items list has grown considerably and also I don't find running an SQL query on each character input appropriate. An alternative way I think is to create a DataSet when the application loads and fill it with the recent stock position upfront. Than use LINQ or something like that to filter the in-memory record-set. But this method is also not optimized because whenever a new bill is created, items from the stock are reduced and each time I will need to update the in-memory record-set.

Is there any other optimized and faster way?

Comment: If this were .NET 4 I'd suggest the Reactive Extensions (Rx): this is one of the examples in the introductory Hands On Lab. But I'm not certain how well pre-v4 is supported.

Comment: What I could also suggest is that you use a min. length before the search query is executed. So for example only run the query when from the moment the search term is more then 3 characters long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few optimizations that can be done

**Database layer**
[Great post](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/presentations/presentation-oscon2000-20000719/) on how to optimize everything on db side

You can also try sharding and horizontal scaling

**Application side**
Do not use dataset, as they are heavy, bulky, slow and make it hard to maintain the same copy of data as on the db. Think over a few tricks:

- Cache user search
- Start searching only after 2 or 3 symbols typed
- Run search in background thread
- Limit search to TOP 20 (or whatever)
- Make sure search is light from various code abstractions, make it simple
- Optimize you search query, order of SQL operations does matter

**Infrastructure**

- Check your connection speed, any possibility to improve it?
- Put your db as close to the application as possible

Answer (score 2):

At work I had something similar but depending on your exact requirements it might not be that helpful. What we did was actually take the app and split off the database querying into some REST services. On the server back end portion we had the application move everything into memory and cache it at start up. We sent all changes through the server so we could invalidate portions of the cache and reload as needed.

On the client side, once a couple characters were entered, we sent a request to the server. The server sent us back the list of items matching that, and we cached it client side. We then just filtered that list client side and only did another request when the field was cleared or the first couple characters were changed.

Even without the server part, you could do something similar with the client side.

Answer (score 2):

Just an extension of what JaCraig is saying, I don't think you need to create the web service but drawing a boundary around this piece of code makes sense as it will be complex.

Moreover, I wouldn't cache the entire database, some tuning and testing could be done to find the correct amount, but I would cache like 10 or 20 items for each character combination up to 2 or maybe 3 characters deep depending on performance (10 items would be ~170k items in memory if not case sensitive and not distincting out the dupes)

Use a hashset for each character addition to return your 10 items, then when they cross the first 3 characters you start querying the database.

The key that JaCraig hit on here is that you would need any updates or modifications to be passed through this same code space to keep your cache clean.

Rationally if you have a DAL, this could just live under there as a seperate dataprovider doing something like:

```
public Items[] GetItems(string searchString)
{
  if (searchString.Length < 4)
  {
    return _cacheDataProvider.GetItems(searchString);
  }

  return _mySqlDataProvider.GetItems(searchString);
}

public void UpdateItem(Item itemToBeUpdated)
{
  _cacheDataProvider.UpdateItem(itemToBeUpdated);
  _mySqlDataProvider.UpdateItem(itemToBeUpdated);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into building a search index off your database using SOLR: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/
and query that in a webservice end point of your choice.

Only sending the query after the user has ceased typing helps a lot as well  I've used about 300 ms as a wait time for when to send the next query.  There are lots of plugins for front end that hit an end-point for you with similar rules if you don't want to build it your self.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at coding in MSIL.  We had a similar scenario whereby we needed to rapidly update the records in memory.  Using the standard .NET way was too slow, so we wrote directly to the memory through playing around with the underlying MSIL.  This is dangerous but if done correctly, you can gain benefits through unmanaged memory use.

[Increasing Application Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647790.aspx#scalenetchapt05_topic34)

Answer (score 0):

The "right" way to solve the look-ahead problem is with a "trie" or "radix tree".  This can be implemented in SQL if need be, though it's a spot of work.  And I'm not sure how easy it would be to adapt to a case where the dataset changes dynamically.

For a "relatively small" dataset (perhaps 10K items max, depending on your environment) the trie could be kept in RAM.

Comment: The right way is actually to use something that implements the data structure you are describing, so you don't have to do it :)  SOLR and Lucene are such technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much flexibility you are allowing in the like clause, but you should be able to tell when the user types in the text box if the new data grid view will be a subset of what you have now - usually it will be because more characters are making the search more specific.

So you could create query the database for a new database only when the new data won't be a subset of what you already have, and save that to a dataset.  When the new data will be a subset, update the dataset's filter.

As far as keeping the data up to date, (if that is what you mean about items in stock changing), you could also have a timer to requery at a reasonable interval.  You could reset the timer when typing in the text box causes a database query, as well as when the timer causes one.